# How can i stop my player from moving in a direction when a collision is made

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Game1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        Rectangle Player;
        Rectangle Enemy;
        Boolean left;
        Boolean right;
        Boolean up;
        Boolean down;

        int Playerx, Playery, Playerw, Playerh;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Playerx = 0;
            Playery = 0;
            Playerw = 32;
            Playerh = 32;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g = e.Graphics;
            //Draw Player
            Player = new Rectangle(Playerx, Playery, Playerw, Playerh);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Player);

            //Draw Enemy
            Enemy = new Rectangle(100, 100, 32, 32);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, Enemy);

            if (Player.IntersectsWith(Enemy.Left))
            {
                left = false;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (left == true)
            {
                Playerx -= 5;
            }

            if (right == true)
            {
                Playerx += 5;
            }

            if (up == true)
            {
                Playery -= 5;
            }

            if (down == true)
            {
                Playery += 5;
            }

            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                left = true;
                right = false;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                right = true;
                left = false;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                up = true;
                down = false;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                down = true;
                up = false;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                left = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                right = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                up = false;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                down = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make the player stop moving when it touches the left side of the enemy but i keep getting an error, and it highlights 
`if (Player.IntersectsWith(Enemy.Left))` and says `Can't convert int into System.Drawing.Rectangle` any ideas?
I have tried to see if this works

```
if (Player.IntersectsWith(Enemy)) 
{
    left = false; 
    right = false; 
    up = false; 
    down = false;
}
```

but of course it keeps the player in place.

Comment: The code you posted is different from the one you claim to have tried. Player.IntersectsWith(Enemy.Left) will give you an error because IntersectsWith expects a Rect and Enemy.Left is an int. If you use Enemy it should compile correctly. I am not sure that the program will do what you want though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a specific collision.

You should try:

```
if(Player.X + Player.Width >= Enemy.X && Player.X < Enemy.X)
{
    right = false;
}
```

This way you are checking if the right side of the player intersects the left side of the enemy and the left side of the players position is less than the left side of the enemy's position (the player is to the left of the enemy)

You will have to add in heights and stuff to that collision to make it so you can pass the enemy but I think for what you have posted it should work ok.

NOTE: Code is untested, let me know how you get on.

Comment: No, i get an error saying X and Width arent a value of System.Drawing.Rectangle

Comment: well I mean Player.X as in use your players X position, it has to have an x Position if you are moving it? And it has to have a width if its a rectangle..

Just put in your playerx + playerw values in there